# Amazon SES add new user to verified domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have my domain name on Godaddy. Trying to set up mail account from amazon ses.

Added my domain name in [Verified Domain Section](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-west-2#verified-senders-domain:) and its verified when added the record (Key Value of Type text) as instructed when adding domain.

- Key => _amazonses.domainname.com
- Value => Some_randoam_string

Now as the domain is verified, Where can I add new smtp accounts, e.g.

user : contact@domainname.com  | password : ***** | HOST : smtphost etc.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SES SMTP credentials are linked to an AWS IAM User.  [Obtaining Your Amazon SES SMTP Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html) describes how to obtain them using a few different techniques.

Note, that the user is unlikely to be an email address such as `contact@domainname.com`, as the SMTP credentials are just used to authorize outbound mail - they are not themselves mail addresses/mailboxes.

Also note that by default, SES is setup in Sandbox mode, so you will only be able to send mail from a verified domain, and TO verified email addresses, so to test, you will also need to [verify any email addresses you want to send to](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html).

[Moving Out of the SES Sandbox](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html) explains how to enable your account for production use.